# Configure Thunderbird to verify DKIM signature and display an icon to this effect?

Tags: email, thunderbird, dkim

Is there any way to configure Thunderbird so that it would verify DKIM signatures of incoming mail, and show a status icon a bit like the HTTPS indicator in browsers?

Comment: I don't know why but @edmaster mentioned [plugin] (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dkim-headers/) is in disabled state

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following extension verifies DKIM signatures:
https://addons.thunderbird.net/thunderbird/addon/dkim-verifier/

Wiki with some more information on the extension: https://github.com/lieser/dkim_verifier/wiki

Comment: Installed it. It works. Hurray! Better late than never :) Thank you so much.

Comment: link now dead, please update

Comment: Updated the link, and added one to the wiki on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

See this extension:
https://github.com/axic/tb-dkim-headers

You may combine it with the [Mnenhy extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/mnenhy/) to show the "Authentication-Results" header.

Comment: Can you expand your answer and add some details?

Comment: It seems that the first extension requires the MTA to add these headers, with all the problems of knowing whether to trust them or not. I don't get why that made it into the RFC; it's totally backwards.

Comment: The linked extension on github doesn't actually perform DKIM verification. It just assumes that somebody else (say, your mail server) has already performed DKIM verification and placed the result in a header. The extension merely exposes this as a column.